# Counterpart to pcl_ros::transformAsMatrix?

Tags: ros, pcl, pcl-ros, tf-conversions, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I understand pcl_ros::transformAsMatrix(const tf::Transform& bt, Eigen::Matrix4f &out_mat) can be used to convert a tf::transform to a 4x4 matrix describing the same transformation.

I am now looking for a method that does the same thing backwards, converting a 4x4 matrix to a tf::transform.

Is such a method already implemented somewhere?

Thanks

EDIT:
Solution that works for me, thanks to Eric:

```
  Eigen::Matrix4f mf; //The matrix I want to convert
  Eigen::Matrix4d md(mf.cast<double>());
  Eigen::Affine3d affine(md);
  tf::Transform transform;
  tf::TransformEigenToTF(affine, transform);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37609/counterpart-to-pcl_ros::transformasmatrix-?/) by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2012-07-01

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) on 2013-11-30**:
A small info which might be helpful for others.
For ROS hydro,
tf::transformEigenToTF must be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should look at the [tf_conversions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf_conversions) package, specifically the [tf::TransformEigenToTF](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/tf_conversions/html/c++/namespacetf.html#ae6f138b15c3fbfb437e2e1b6eba659e1) function.

You would have to make an `Eigen::Affine3d` from your `Eigen::Matrix4f`. See the [Eigen Geometry Module Tutorial](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialGeometry.html) (and linked docs for each class) for information on how to go about that. I expect it involves a conversion from Matrix4f to Matrix4d and then passing that to the Affine3d constructor, but I don't know the exact function calls and syntax required off the top of my head.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) on 2012-07-01**:
Works, thank you.

**Comment by [bzr](https://answers.ros.org/users/20986/bzr/) on 2014-12-02**:
The Eigen Geometry Module Tutorial no longer exists. Is there an updated version?